# Neo4j: Node versus Node property

Tags: neo4j

I am developing a Neo4j database that will contain genomic and clinical data for cancer patients. A common design issue in developing graph databases is whether a data item should be represented by a Node or by a property within a Node. In my case, patients will have hundreds of clinical and demographic measurements (e.g. sex, medications, tumor size). Some of these data will be constant (e.g. sex) while others will be subject to variation with each patient visit. The responses I've seen to previous node vs property questions have recommended using the anticipated queries against the data to make the decision. I think I can identify some properties that will be common search criteria and should be nodes (e.g. smoking history, sex, cancer type) but that still leaves me with hundreds of other properties. Is there a practical limit in Neo4j for the number of properties that a Node should contain? Also, a hybrid approach, where some data are properties and others are Nodes would seem to make both loading data from source files and subsequent queries more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

The main idea behind "look at your queries to decide", is that how data relates to each other effects whether a node or property is better. Really, the main point of a graph database is to make walking relationships easier to query. So the real question you should ask yourself is "Does (a)-->()<--(b) have any significant meaning?" In other words, do I need to be able to find other nodes that share this property?

Here are some quick rule-of-thumb guidlines

**Node**

- Has it's own sub-values or relations
- Multiple nodes sharing this value has meaning, and you need to be able to walk along this shared value between them
- Changes infrequently
- If more than 1 value can apply at the same time

**Properties**

- Has a large range of possible values
- Changes over time
- If more than 1 value can apply, values are usually updated as a set (rather than individually)

**Label**

- Has a small, finite range of mutually exclusive values
- Almost never changes

So lets go through the thought process of a few of your properties...

**Sex**

Will either be "Male" or "Female", and everyone will be connected to one of the two, so they will both end up being super nodes (overloaded). Also, if you do end up needing to find two people that share the same sex, almost any other method would be more efficient than finding them through the super node. However these are mutually exclusive, immutable, genetic traits so making this a label is also perfectly acceptable (and sometimes preferred).

**Address**

This is a variable value with sub-properties, won't be shared by very many nodes, and the walk from one person to another at the same address (or, by extension, live in an area) has valuable meaning. So this should almost definitely be a node.

**Height and Weight**

These change constantly with time, have no sub values, and two people sharing this value has little to no meaning. The range of values is far too wide, so Labels make no since either, so this should be a property.

**Blood type**

While has more options then Sex does, all the same logic applies, except that the relation does matter now (because people must share a blood type to donate). The problem is that this value will be so overloaded, that you will need to filter on area first, and than just verifying blood type. Could be a property or label. The case for node is if you include an "Can_Donate_To" or "Can_Accept" relation between the blood types. While you likely won't walk these relations to find a potential donor (because they are too overloaded, and you will have to filter by area first), you can use them to verify someone can be a donor.

**Social Security Number**

Is highly sensitive, and a lawsuit waiting to happen. Keep out of the DB if at all possible. If you absolutely have to; this property is immutable, but will be unique to every person, so because of the lack of reuse, is a bad label and will be pointless as a node. Definitely a property. (But should be salted+hashed if only for verification purposes only)

**Mother's maiden name**

The possible values are endless, and two nodes sharing this value has no real meaning. Definitely a property.

**First born child**

Since the child is already their own node, with it's own sub properties, just create a relation between the two. While the value of this info is questionable, any time you need to reference another node, always use a relationship for it. Definitely a node.